# LinkageError on a AXIS WebService

Tags: java, web-services, axis

EDIT:
Two -1. I cannot understand this. I have a problem that is not clear at all due to the impossible message given. I did all the possible research but seems to be impossible to find. If this seems to be so "easy" for you so you could at least do the effort to comment or provide an answer.

The thing is that SO is **full** of Android "SocketException" due to manifest permission problem or basic NullPointerException, and those imo are "question with no research efforts".

Please, next time be polite and constructive and at least explain the reason behind the downvote.

---

Ok, I'm getting this LinkageError while calling a WebService with AXIS. The client was automatically generated in order to user Weblogic but I cannot understand where is the problem..

Please, leave aside any "dispose that garbage" because it's all legacy code.. (I'm developing on a virtualized XP with NetBeans 6.5 so you can imagine......)

This is the error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: (Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:338)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:291)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:259)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:54)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:40)
    at some.package.from.us.callServiceAxis(Users.java:277)
    at some.package.from.us.Users.verify(Users.java:90)
    at some.package.from.us.login(ServiceApp.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
```

What the heck this is meant to be? -> `(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/rmi/Remote;`

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This error occurs because the class referred is being changed. Make sure you are deploying the updated code/ check your jars also.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide a more wide explanation on the steps to follow to check this and put it as an answer? [btw I still don't get the -1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've resolved creating another stub with Eclipse.

Still don't know wich was the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your updated webservices class into the weblogic server. and then use the wsdl location to create the client again. and then try. I think you are using weblogic test client. So simply re-deploy your webservices and test.